# Cocoapods fails "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: macos, firebase, curl, openssl, cocoapods

When I try to install a Cocoapod (Firebase), I see this issue.

```
Installing Firebase (4.7.0)

[!] Error installing Firebase
[!] /usr/local/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/xv/ghl7s0wx2m3_0hwh15spwfrc0000gn/T/d20171222-26613-2tuztl/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/51a9c1fa1090163e/Firebase-4.7.0.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional

curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You might have rebuilt or replaced `curl` with a version that doesn't have SSL support.

To fix it you'll need to make sure the `curl` version is built with SLL. Follow these steps:

- Download and install OpenSSL
- https://www.openssl.org/source/
- On Mac:

  ```
      ./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl \
              -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/ssl/lib
      make
      sudo make install
  ```
- Install curl on Mac with SSL configured, otherwise your curl commands with `https` will fail.

  - On Mac:

    ```
    ./configure --with-ssl
    make
    sudo make install
    ```
  - Verify that SSL is setup after your configure step, you should see something like the following text:

    ```
     SSL support:      enabled (OpenSSL)
    ```
- Now try to install your Cocoapods.

  ```
       pod install
  ```
- You should see the `https` curl dependencies complete:

  ```
  Analyzing dependencies
  Downloading dependencies
  Installing Firebase (4.8.0)
  Installing FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.5)
  Installing FirebaseCore (4.0.13)
  ```